# date-fns format time in 24 hour format

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I'm using date-fns in a React project.

```
const sampleText = 'Tue Aug 03 2021 18:49:11 GMT+0800';
const sampleDate = new Date(sampleText);
format(sampleDate, 'hh:mm')
```

This returns '06:49'. How can I get this to return '18:49' instead?

Comment: https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/format. Try `HH:mm`

Comment: `sampleText.substring(16,21)` or as local time `new Date('Tue Aug 03 2021 18:49:11 GMT+0800').toLocaleString('en',{hour:'2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12:false})`. Oh sorry, no library…

Answer (score 18):

The format tokens for date-fns can be found here: https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/format

```
const sampleText = 'Tue Aug 03 2021 18:49:11 GMT+0800';
const sampleDate = new Date(sampleText);
format(sampleDate, 'HH:mm')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is also another option which uses 'kk:mm:ss' format:

```
const sampleText = 'Tue Aug 03 2021 18:49:11 GMT+0800';
const sampleDate = new Date(sampleText);
format(sampleDate, 'kk:mm:ss')
```

Comment: What does that add to the initial answer? Also, the question specifically asked for `HH:mm`.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. You just have to remove the `ss` from the format. See the documentation referenced above.